# After deploying django project to heroku, error below shows up if i try to create new user or sign in, I am using the sqlite3 database

Tags: django, authentication, heroku

relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."userna...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you have not applied migrations. Try `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.